# Microsoft SQL Server Express Java Connection

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, connection, sql-server-express

I installed on proxmox a SQL Server Express and now I want connect with a Java program to it, to write and read data. But no matter what I do, I don't get a connection. I tested different types of code for the connection URL, I find some different about the last years. So does anybody now what type of URL I have to use? Maybe somebody can write a example program.
PS: I can connect to the SQL Server via SQL Server Management Studio, so the connection it self work

Thanks for help

I tried different types of URL input:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.178.42:1433"
            + "database=test;"
            + "user=ftm-server;"
            + "password=test;"
            + "encrypt=true;"
            + "trustServerCertificate=false;"
            + "loginTimeout=30;";
```

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.178.42:1433;databaseName=test;user=ftm-server;password=test";
```

Comment: Express, by default, doesn't run on port 1433, are you sure you changed it to that static port?

Comment: Also, you say you don't a get a connection, so what error are you getting? I note, as well, that you don't trust the certificate, but use a  encryoted connection. SQL Server installs come with a self signed cert, so have you added you own trusted cert to the instance?

Comment: Add how your connection window looks in SSMS, it might help out

Comment: Please see the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that it doesn't matter if you concatenate the string but the first one is different to the second and certainly misses a separator after 1433.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.